# Error SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value

Tags: php, sql

So I'm working on a project of "product Insertion". Everything went perfect until i've a added a categories_id element...
And I got this error :  SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value.

Here is my code :

The way I display my categories :

```
 <select name="cate" id="">
        <option value="">Choisissez la catégorie de votre choix</option>
        <?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>

        <option value="<?= $category["id"] ?>"><?= $category["id"] ?> - <?= $category["label"] ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
```

The way I get my value

```
$cate = $_POST["cate"];

$cate = (int)$cate;
```

Query + stmt :

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO produits VALUES(NULL, :titre, :categories_id, :img1, :img2, :text1, :text2, :text3, :code, :designation, :ean, :pnu, :emballage, :scolisage, :colisage, :pnuu, :packaging, :carac, :contenu)";
$stmt->bindValue(':categories_id', $cate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

(I did not show you every 20 lines about the others but they are working perfectly until this categories_id..)

And the function that display the categories

```
function getAllCategories()
```

{

```
global $connexion;
$query = "SELECT * FROM categories";
$stmt = $connexion->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();

return $stmt->fetchAll();
```

}

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: It sounds like your category_id column in your database is a date-type field... Or, because you are using INSERT without providing the list of columns, it means the second column in your "produits" table may not be the field you expect (category_id) Try listing your fields in your query: "INSERT INTO produits(id, titre, categories_id, ...) VALUES(...)"

Comment: please type ```select * from `produits` ``` in your database, and we can know what your ```category_id```'s type is. Maybe it is **date***, you can change it to ```int(11)```